# IIS Authentication Not Working

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, permissions, iis-6

Problem: Keep getting prompt for user & pass.

I have tried quite a bit of configurations and I can't seem to make it work or authenticate properly.

I have one site working properly in same server but the new one I created doesn't authenticate when set to 'Integrated Windows Authentication'. Webconfig also has Windows as authentication method, but the site still prompts for logon user. This info should be automatically picked up from current windows logon user on the server.

The directory where site resides has proper permissions I believe 'IIS_USR', 'DOMAINUSERSGROUP', etc.

Unsure what else to check to make it work. I have compared both applications webconfig and look very similar. One is 1.4 the other 2.0 .net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're testing on the machine itself, it's likely this: http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=896861.  Contrary to what the doc says, a reboot isn't required.

If it's not that, the user that needs access to disk is your own that you're logging in as, plus the app pool identity.  I bet it's the loopback check though.

Comment: It was the loopback and host headers. I ended up adding the site to Local Intranet in IE and it worked.